# Permissions when crossing over from Windows to Mac

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to work locally on a Mac installation of Craft but keep getting permissions errors with Storage, and so on. I don't get these errors when working locally on Windows using these same files (synced using Dropbox).

Is there a way to fix this without manually changing every file? I've changed the permissions for Storage and Runtime but am now getting *Unable to create a cache directory*. Even if there is a fix, will I need to repeat it for each project I create on Windows and later work on using the Mac?

Cheers,
Clive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a nearly identical setup... a Windows 8.1 box using IIS and an OSX laptop using MAMP with Craft installs that are sync'd with Dropbox between them.

If I recall correctly, the only thing I did was give "Everyone" full recursive access to things like `craft/storage` on Windows and `chmod -R 777 craft/storage` on the OSX box.

Haven't ran into any permission issues.

I will warn you *not* to use symlinks in that setup, however, as Dropbox doesn't know how to resolve those cross platform.

Comment: Thanks Brad - it's good to know you're working similarly. I've got it working on the Mac, now, so will work on it on Windows tomorrow and see what it's like when I return.